# Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need to render a component say 'PrintersField' inside another component say 'SamplesPrinters'.

SamplesPrinters:
There are some event listeners in SamplesPrinters listening to any change in state that occurs and is placed inside ComponentDidMount().
Some functions calling the dispatcher to dispatch the actions.
While one the action is currently dispatching, it changes the state, so component gets re-rendered.
Rendering of component renders 'PrintersField'as well.

PrintersField:
Component PrintersField also has some actions to be dispatched in its ComponentDidMount().
When it starts dispatching, it is where the issue occurs as the component SamplesPrinters action is dispatching and it's not complete yet.

console error message: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.

Tried with delaying dispatching an action using setTimeout(). But that is not suitable for our application.

SamplesPrinters.jsx

```
function getPrintersState() {
  return {
    detailsList: PrintersStore.DetailsList(),
    formState: PrintersStore.formState()
    };
}

class SamplesPrinters extends React.Component {
  state = getPrintersState();
  componentDidMount() {
    PrintersStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange);
    PrintersActions.initCurrentUser(this.props.current_user);
     }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    PrintersStore.removeChangeListener(this.onChange);
  }

  render() {
    let printerButton;
      printerButton = (
        <div className="docked-footer”>
            <PrintersField
            />
        );
      return (
      <div className="Login">
        <PrintersForm formState={this.state.formState} />
        {printerButton}
      </div>
    );
  }

  onChange = () => {
     this.setState(getPrintersState());
  };

module.exports = SamplesPrinters;
```

PrintersField.jsx

```
class PrintersField extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    PrinterTestStore.addChangeListener(this.handleListChange);

    if (!PrinterTestStore.loading() && this.state.Printers.length === 0) {
      DataActions.initPrinters();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
  PrinterTestStore.removeChangeListener(this.handleListChange);
  }

  render() {
      return (
      <SelectField
        className={classname}
        name="Printer"
        options={this.state.Printers}
        onSelectionChange={this.handleSelectChange}
        error={presentedError}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  }
}

module.exports = PrintersField;
```

PrintersActions.js

```
const  PrintersActions  =

initCurrentUser: function (value) {
  ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
      AppDispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: Actions.GET_PRINTERSVALUE_PROCESSING
      });
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: URIUtils.createURI(‘/printers/test’, { accession: value }),
    success: function (data) {
      AppDispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: Actions.GET_PRINTERSVALUE_SUCCESS,
        accessions: data
      });     
  });
}
};
```

DataActions.js

```
const DataActions = {

initPrinters: function () {
    ajax({
      beforeSend: function () {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
          actionType: DataConstants.Actions.GET_PRINTERS_STARTING
        });
      },
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/ref_data/printers',
      success: function (data) {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
          actionType: DataConstants.Actions.GET_PRINTERS_SUCCESS,
          printers: data
        });
      },
      error: function () {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
          actionType: DataConstants.Actions.GET_PRINTERS_FAIL
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

PrintersStore.js

```
...

let _DetailsList = [];

    const PrintersStore = Object.assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
   …
  DetailsList: function () {
    return _DetailsList;
  },

  emitChange: function () {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
  },

  addChangeListener: function (callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },

  removeChangeListener: function (callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }
   …
});

 AppDispatcher.register((action) => {
      switch (action.actionType) {
       …
        case SamplesLoginConstants.Actions.GET_PRINTERSVALUE_SUCCESS:
          addPrintersToList(action.accessions);
          break;
       …
        default:
          return;
      }

    function addPrintersToList(accessions) {
      for (let h = 0; h < accessions.length; h += 1) {
        const accession = accessions[h];

        const existingAccession = find(_DetailsList, { id: accession.id });
        const addOnSpecifier = [];

        if (existingAccession) {
          remove(_DetailsList, { id: accession.id });
          for (let i = 0; i < accession.sampleSpecifiers.length; i += 1) {
            const specifier = accession.sampleSpecifiers[I];
            if (!(find(existingAccession.sampleSpecifiers, { id: container.id }))) {
              addOnSpecifier.push(specifier);
            }
          }
          if (addOnSpecifier.length) {
              existingAccession.sampleContainers =
              existingAccession.sampleContainers.concat(addOnSpecifier);
          }
          _DetailsList.unshift(existingAccession);
        } else {
          accession.status = null;
          _DetailsList.unshift(accession);
        }
      }
    }
...
```

Comment: Can you please add source for `PrintersActions.initCurrentUser(this.props.current_user);` and `DataActions.initPrinters();` If I understand correctly these actions conflicting

Comment: Hi @Fyodor I have added the source. When I check logs I see issue in DataConstants.Actions.GET_PRINTERS_SUCCESS , the action is not finsihed dispatching and PrintersField is rendered and initPrinters is dispatched.

Comment: Please show the reducer code. Actions should be dispatched instantly

Comment: @Fyodor Added and modified SamplesPrinters.jsx for better understanding

Comment: I still don't understand logic (reducer should be pure function of state and action, but I don't see so). But nevertheless, I see that `addPrintersToList` have nested loops and may process data awhile. I may recommend to move this code to action creator and when `_DetailsList` is updated just dispatch update `_DetailsList` to reducer

Comment: Even I thought the same, but it is not happening that way. If I dispatch an action and in reducer it justs simply updates the states(1 line of code ). The PrintersField is rendered and initPrinters() is called which again dispatches an action. Till then, the earlier dispatch has not finished yet.